# How to split rows into to two rows in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I generated a table with "query method", now I would like to split each row generated into two rows. Like on this image.

[image: Before-After]

I thought to use filter method, but without success. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vme7g.png) You can do this using this technique:

1. First, add a column on the left side. And dd odd numbers in the newly created sheet
2. Now add a new column before the 2nd table even numbers in this column
3. Now copy the second table data below the 1st table
4. Finally sort column one...hope that make sense.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).